# How can I prevent PATH errors while developing Ruby in Windows (7)? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ruby, windows, path

It seems every week I have to clean up the environment variables, uninstall all gems (I've even memorized the one liner command by now) and reinstall Ruby, DevKit, Gems, Rails, Heroku, etc. Most of the time it works and it's ok for a few days, but it's not long before the "`x` is not recognized as an internal or external command" or "The native gem requires installed build tools" errors start creeping up, until development becomes impossible.

Surely this can't be normal, but as far as I know I'm not doing anything explicitly wrong. I do things the same way I used to do on my Mac, and it just worked. But I'm at the end of my rope with this OS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sarcastically, do it all on Unix. Seriously, could you post the one liner you to install everything and your current path?

Comment: Question: are you changing/adding/removing programs that alter PATH? how you installed Ruby/DevKit? Used the installer and followed the DevKit installation instructions? Do you relocate Ruby's installation folder every week? Have you used `Start command prompt with Ruby` to start a command prompt with Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Really all you should need is to have the Ruby you're using's bin folder at the *start* of your PATH (start for safety sake).  And make sure you don't have any others in there.

For the "requires installed build tools" I usually just add these to the system path, your equivalent:

C:\installs\devkit451\devkit451\bin;C:\installs\devkit451\devkit451\mingw\bin;

HTH.

Comment: Actually, if the user follow the DevKit installation instructions, then there is no need to add DevKits directory to the PATH.